# Removing pepper noise and salt noise from images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to process images with salt noise and pepper noise in Matlab.

Which filter: `median`, `opening`, or `closing` performs the best in removing salt noise (white pixels)?

Which one is the best for pepper noise (black pixels)?

Comment: Median works well for both. You should try all 3 on specific test images to know what works best for your own situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Opening** - is the composite function of `dilation` and `erosion`. That means that it is erosion followed by dilation. What erosion means is that if we have a structuring element that is a `3 X 3 matrix`,  the central pixel will be replaced by the darkest pixel in the `3 X 3 neighborhood`. Opening is erosion followed by dilation which makes it **perfect for removing salt noise (white dots)** and ensuring that the key features are relatively sharp.

**Closing** is dilation followed by erosion. Dilation means that the central pixel will be replaced by the brightest pixel in the vicinity (filter structural element). **Perfect for removing pepper noise** and ensuring that the key features are relatively sharp.

Answer (score 3):

Median filter should be good for both salt and pepper noise because they occur at random pixels. Opening and closing will affect the other objects as well so they are not for general way to remove salt and peppers.

Answer (score 1):

use simple adaptive `median` filter:
for all `pixels` in the image
if the pixel black or white replace the pixel by the median of its neighbors.

Of course there are better methods but they are more complicated.

Cheer