# How to getting a SOLID blob for each object using findcontours?

Tags: opencv, blob, contour, object-detection

I wanna segementing a solid blobs for each object from extracted foreground and bounding each object with a box. But my code show many boxes bounding random blobs on 1 object, because my blob is not solid for 1 object and there're many small blobs too.

Here we go my code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;                                              
    cv::Mat fg;                                                 
    cv::Mat thresholded;
    cv::Mat thresholded2;
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::Mat bgmodel;                                            
    cv::namedWindow("Frame");                                   
    cv::namedWindow("Background Model");                        
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);                                    

    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs;                           

        bgs.nmixtures = 2;                                      
        bgs.history = 60;
        bgs.varThreshold = 15;
        bgs.bShadowDetection = true;                            
        bgs.nShadowDetection = 0;                               
        bgs.fTau = 0.5;                                         

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;               

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;                                           

        cv::blur(frame,frame,cv::Size(10,10));

        bgs.operator()(frame,fg);                           
        bgs.getBackgroundImage(bgmodel);                    

        cv::erode(fg,fg,cv::Mat());                         
        cv::dilate(fg,fg,cv::Mat());                        

        cv::threshold(fg,thresholded,70.0f,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::threshold(fg,thresholded2,70.0f,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::findContours(thresholded,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::cvtColor(thresholded2,result,CV_GRAY2RGB);

        int cmin= 50; 
        int cmax= 10000;

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>::iterator itc=contours.begin();

        while (itc!=contours.end()) {       
                if (itc->size() < cmin || itc->size() > cmax){
                    itc= contours.erase(itc);} else{

                        std::vector<cv::Point> pts = *itc;
                        cv::Mat pointsMatrix = cv::Mat(pts);
                        cv::Scalar color( 0, 255, 0 );

                        cv::Rect r0= cv::boundingRect(pointsMatrix);
                        cv::rectangle(result,r0,color,2);

                        ++itc;
                    }
        }

        cv::imshow("Frame",result);
        cv::imshow("Background Model",bgmodel);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the result here:
[Frame](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/13697987232930461.png)

so how I can segmenting a solid blob for each object found from extracted foreground, and bounding the object on by one with the box?

a solid blob mean a solid white blob like here: xxx

I'll apreciating any help here.

NB: Sorry for my bad English. :)

=================

This is my edited code!

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat frame;                                              
    cv::Mat fg;     
    cv::Mat blurred;
    cv::Mat thresholded;
    cv::Mat thresholded2;
    cv::Mat result;
    cv::Mat bgmodel;                                            
    cv::namedWindow("Frame");                                   
    cv::namedWindow("Background Model");                        
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);    

    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs;                           

        bgs.nmixtures = 2;                                      
        bgs.history = 60;
        bgs.varThreshold = 15;
        bgs.bShadowDetection = true;                            
        bgs.nShadowDetection = 0;                               
        bgs.fTau = 0.5;                                         

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;               

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;                                           

        cv::blur(frame,blurred,cv::Size(10,10));

        bgs.operator()(blurred,fg);                         
        bgs.getBackgroundImage(bgmodel);                                    

        cv::threshold(fg,thresholded,70.0f,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::threshold(fg,thresholded2,70.0f,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat element50(50,50,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(1));
        cv::morphologyEx(thresholded,thresholded,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,element50);
        cv::morphologyEx(thresholded2,thresholded2,cv::MORPH_CLOSE,element50);

        cv::findContours(thresholded,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        cv::cvtColor(thresholded2,result,CV_GRAY2RGB);

        int cmin= 50; 
        int cmax= 10000;

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>::iterator itc=contours.begin();

        while (itc!=contours.end()) {   

                if (itc->size() < cmin || itc->size() > cmax){
                    itc= contours.erase(itc);} else{ 

                        std::vector<cv::Point> pts = *itc;
                        cv::Mat pointsMatrix = cv::Mat(pts);
                        cv::Scalar color( 0, 255, 0 );

                        cv::Rect r0= cv::boundingRect(pointsMatrix);
                        cv::rectangle(result,r0,color,2);

                        ++itc;
                    }
        }

        cv::imshow("Frame",result);
        cv::imshow("Background Model",bgmodel);
        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the result here: [FRAME](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/1369818820240372.png)

Thanks to elactic. :)

Comment: Could you define "solid" and "object" more explicitly? thx.

Comment: object mean detected object from foreground.

Comment: solid mean a solid white blob without holes for 1 object.

Comment: Are you trying to filter out all the small blobs and the blobs that have holes, or are you looking for a solution to find the "person" in the image as a single object and draw a bounding box around it?

Comment: both, I wanna filter out all the small blobs (solved) and merge the object blobs into the biggest blob (white solid blob without black holes).

Comment: after that find the object (not only person but every captured object in front of camera) and draw a bounding box around it (I think this case will be solved after the biggest blob segmented).

Comment: I am afraid without any knowledge on how the object looks like, it's difficult to merge blobs. And even if you succeed, the object may still have holes (for example, if your object is a lifebuoy).

Comment: oh i see, hmmm do you have a way to merge the blobs? and it's okay if the blob has holes.. I wanna find the biggest blob as an object, and bounding it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to merge blogs with morphological closing (which is the erosion of the dilation of a binary image). You can use the CV functions `erode` and `dilate` for that.

[This tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/opencv-image-processing-morphological-filters) should help you.
I assume you will still have to filter blobs by size after that.

Comment: didn't work, I've tried this method follow this link: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806968/edge-smoothing-and-filling-inner-contours-in-opencv-with-ios)

Comment: I've tried to using dilate and erode thresholded image, and tada! my app bounding a object! Thanks! Now I need to merge blobs correctly to tracking them :D

Comment: Cool!
You can also use erosion and dilation for filtering the noise, maybe as a first step... See this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452942/removing-pepper-noise-and-salt-noise-from-images

Comment: Now I need to combine dilation and erosion correctly to cover a black hole on the blob and filter out all the noise (white blob on the black background). anyway thank you very much! :D

Comment: Finally, [Result](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/1369818820240372.png) Thanks again @elactic :D